How do I annotate duplicate values in a column using Pandas
I have a dataset containing a column with lots of duplicated rows. My column looks something like the Index Column in the table below:



Index
New_Column




2020BAS
2020BAS


2022CAD
2022CAD


2012BET
2012BET_1


2012BET
2012BET_2


2012BET
2012BET_3


2008TEQ
2008TEQ


2021JET
2021JET_1


2021JET
2021JET_2


2011ART
2011ART_1


2011ART
2011ART_2


2011ART
2011ART_3


2019QAS
2019QAS


2010POS
2010POS_1


2010POS
2010POS_2


2010POS
2010POS_3


2010POS
2010POS_4


2016YIG
2016YIG


2017LIM
2017LIM



Using Pandas, I would like to create a new column that contains the rows in the Index Column and add numbered annotations to all duplicate occurrences of a specific row item. The result I have in mind can be seen in the New_Column series in the table above.
I have been searching here and elsewhere and still cannot find any examples of this issue or a proposed solution. Admittedly, I am new to Python and am still trying to figure out how to go about this issue. Any help would be a tremendous learning experience

You can use a .groupby('Index').cumcount() to get the counts of duplicated values, convert those values to the appropriate string suffix and add it back to the original column:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': [
        '2020BAS', '2022CAD', '2012BET', '2012BET', '2012BET', '2008TEQ',
        '2021JET', '2021JET', '2011ART', '2011ART', '2011ART', '2019QAS',
        '2010POS', '2010POS', '2010POS', '2010POS', '2016YIG', '2017LIM',
    ]
})

df['New_Column'] = df['Index'] + df.groupby('Index').cumcount().apply(lambda v: f'_{v}' if v > 0 else '')

print(df)
#       Index New_Column
# 0   2020BAS    2020BAS
# 1   2022CAD    2022CAD
# 2   2012BET    2012BET
# 3   2012BET  2012BET_1
# 4   2012BET  2012BET_2
# 5   2008TEQ    2008TEQ
# 6   2021JET    2021JET
# 7   2021JET  2021JET_1
# 8   2011ART    2011ART
# 9   2011ART  2011ART_1
# 10  2011ART  2011ART_2
# 11  2019QAS    2019QAS
# 12  2010POS    2010POS
# 13  2010POS  2010POS_1
# 14  2010POS  2010POS_2
# 15  2010POS  2010POS_3
# 16  2016YIG    2016YIG
# 17  2017LIM    2017LIM


Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly the solution I wanted. Amazing. Much indebted
